# Root domain is not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns, zerigo

I setup Zerigo DNS addon at my Heroku app using Heroku instructions for adding a custom domain. It works fine when you open www.spotty.rs.

I also added spotty.rs as a domain in Heroku panel, and added a REDIRECT record at Zerigo (redirection to www.spotty.rs). When I type spotty.rs in browser sometimes it redirects me to www.spotty.rs and sometimes I got Application error. In console, heroku log command displays H70 error which states that DNS records are not set correctly.

Any idea why is this happening? I made this changes two days ago. Is it possible that it still takes time to propagate DNS changes?!

Comment: At this moment spotty.rs is redirecting to www.spotty.rs without H70 error.

Comment: Last night, and now, it is not working..

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, you need to go to the url zerigo settings of your app, for example: https://zerigo-dashboard.heroku.com/apps/% nameofyourappheroku% an click "Configure" in the DNS menu click "Add snippet" and select "Heroku" to finish click the button "Add select records"

After CNAME edit and put the URL of your site on heroku, example "yourapp.herokuapp.com"

This will take a few minutes.