# heroku zerigo dns - www.xxx.in working but xxx.in sometimes giving application error (sometimes working)

Tags: heroku, zerigo

I am custom domain for my heroku app using zerigo dns.

www.domain.in is working fine.

domain.com should redirect to www.domain.in sometimes and sometimes giving application error.

Records in zerigo dns :

```
 1) type: redirect, domain.in, http://www.domain.in

 2) www.domain.in, cname, xxx.herokuapp.com

 another 3 A type records
```

I think these are correct thats why sometimes it is working, but sometimes giving application error, as of now thinking that it is zerigo bug.

Related question I found - [Root domain is not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19111689/root-domain-is-not-working-properly)

Answer (score 0):

This setup should work on three conditions:

1. Your root DNS has A records pointing to Heroku's designated routing IPs
2. You have added your naked domain to your application (`heroku domains:add example.com`)
3. Your application supports your naked domain

Check all these points, a problem in each one can cause things not to work.

If you are redirecting on the DNS/host provider level from the naked domain to `www.` then none of this is needed, and you have a configuration problem with your host which is out of scope for this question.

Comment: If there is something wrong, why its working sometimes ? Someother also have same problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19111689/root-domain-is-not-working-properly